# CADisplayLink because of remove(from:forMode:) not deallocating view controller

Tags: ios, swift, cadisplaylink

I am facing one strange issue.

So I have created instance and allocated like below

```
var displayLink:CADisplayLink?

private func setupDisplayLink () {

    self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkDidFire(link:)))
    self.displayLink?.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
    self.displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
}
```

Now to remove display link I have from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53812601/4601900)

```
self.displayLink?.remove(from: .main, forMode: .common) // comment this line and view controller correctly deallocated 
self.displayLink?.invalidate()
```

because of line  `self.displayLink?.remove(from: .main, forMode: .common)` my `deinit` method not called of view controller

In memory graph I am not able to identify the real problem. I was lucky that I have  tried to comment that line and it works

[image]

Why that so ?

Answer (score 0):

Stop displayLink like this:

```
displayLink?.invalidate()
displayLink = nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ya that's I know , But question is why remove method not allowing the view controller to deallocate ?